# Running -march optimized software on another architechture?

Tags: gcc, 64bit, virtualization, x86

I'm running an Athlon64 server with LFS and would like to have a local copy of the server in a virtual machine for testing purposes and building software.

My PC uses an i7 and the existing server software was built with -march=athlon64. Despite the optimizations am I able to run this on my hardware?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [-march](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) flag permits the compiler to use instructions that are not supported by other CPUs. There are a few instructions that are legal to use with `-march=athlon64` that your i7 does not support. These are the 3DNow! and Enhanced 3DNow! instructions that weren't included in MMX or integer SSE. If the code uses instructions like [PFPNACC](http://asm.inightmare.org/opcodelst/index.php?op=PFPNACC) it will fault on your i7.

That said, it's extremely unlikely that it actually does use any such instructions because those instructions have generally been found to be of little use -- the useful 3DNow! instructions were incorporated into MMX or iSSE, which your CPU does support.

So it's not guaranteed to work, but it probably will.

> **-march=cpu-type**: Generate instructions for the machine type `cpu-type`. ... `-march=cpu-type` allows GCC to generate code that **may not run at all on processors other than the one indicated**.

Comment: Do you know if Qemu is capable of emulating Athlon64 instruction sets?

Comment: I know that support was [developed in 2008](http://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-devel@nongnu.org/msg16531.html). I don't know whether it got merged into the main distribution though.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to run it, although with a small performance penalty.

Comment: How do you figure? What if it uses enhanced 3DNow instructions like [PFPNACC](http://asm.inightmare.org/opcodelst/index.php?op=PFPNACC)?

Comment: The basic architecture is the same (x86 64-bit), so it will run. But since the binary is optimized for an Athlon, with its specific instructions, it won't run as well as if it were compiled optimized for an i7.

Comment: The question was if it will run. My answer is yes, it will.

Comment: He's asking about [-march](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html), not `-mtune`. It's not "optimized" for athlon64, it set to use the athlon64's instruction set. This includes instructions like PFPNACC that the i7 does not support.

Comment: Quoting from the manual: `-march=cpu-type
           Generate instructions for the machine type cpu-type.  The choices for cpu-type are the same as for -mtune.  Moreover, specifying -march=cpu-type implies -mtune=cpu-type.
`. And `-mtune=cpu-type Tune to cpu-type everything applicable about the generated code, except for the ABI and the set of available instructions.`

Comment: Right, so `-march` is not an optimization option (like `-mtune`), it's a code generation option. The doc for [-march](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) says, "Generate instructions for the machine type cpu-type. **In contrast to -mtune=cpu-type, which merely tunes the generated code for the specified cpu-type, -march=cpu-type allows GCC to generate code that may not run at all on processors other than the one indicated**."